# How do I install 16.04.

Tags: system-installation

Burnt 16.04 iso to disk. Won't boot to disk even though bios set to cd/dvd as 1st boot. Install folder on disk does not have installable file. Win7 Pro  system. Help please.

Comment: You need to boot from the disk. If your system can't boot from it, or a disk is bad, there is no way to fix it.

Comment: Can you use a USB? If so, try flashing it to a USB with Universal USB Installer, works for me

Comment: You cannot just copy the .iso to the disk, you have to install it.  https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BurningIsoHowto

Answer (score 0):

Did you just copy the iso file to the disk or did you burn it with an iso writer like win32diskImager? 
If not, do that. If you did that, check the cd to see if you can read it.

Comment: You'll have to use a program like iso cd or free iso burner. Win32diskImager only works for sd cards. I haven't used a cd/dvd in years, so I didn't know.
Explanation here on how to do it.
https://www.lifewire.com/how-to-burn-an-iso-image-file-to-a-dvd-2626156